# Llamar a Controlador con parametros desde evento click de radio button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Controlador

```
public ActionResult Index(string Color, string Numero)
{
    return View();
}
```

En la vista (simplificado)...

```
<div id=”radioColor”>
   <input type=”radio” id=”Color” name=”Color” value=”rojo″ >Rojo</input >
   <input type=”radio” id=”Color” name=”Color” value=”azul″ >Azul</input >
</div>

<div id=”radioNumero”>
   <input type=”radio” id=”Numero” name=”Numero” value=”uno″ >Uno</input >
   <input type=”radio” id=”Numero” name=”Numero” value=”dos″ >Dos</input >
</div>
```

Al hacer clic en cualquier radio, debería llamar al controlador Index con los valores del radioColor y radioNumero actualmente seleccionados

Comment: falta asignarle el evento `onclick` a cada **radioButton**; ese onclick debe llamar a una función creada por ti, donde utilices `$.ajax` para comunicarte con tu método